# How can I instantiate class variables that are instances of a class?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a `Vector2` class, and I would like to define a few Vector2s, i.e. unit up, unit right, zero, etc, as class variables. The following code, however, insists that Vector2 is not defined.

```
from collections import deque,namedtuple
from typing import ClassVar

@dataclass
class Vector2:
    UNIT_UP    : ClassVar = Vector2(0,1)
    UNIT_DOWN  : ClassVar = Vector2(0,-1)
    UNIT_LEFT  : ClassVar = Vector2(-1,0)
    UNIT_RIGHT : ClassVar = Vector2(1,0)
    ZERO       : ClassVar = __class__(0,0) # this approach doesn't work either

    x : int = 0
    y : int = 0

    # some math dunders
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create an instance of a class within its own body because the body needs to finish running before the class object can be created. The namespace the body of the class runs in becomes the class namespace.

To do what you want, you need to create the class first, then assign the class attributes afterwards. You can probably do this without putting anything specific about the attributes in the class at all:

```
class Foo:
   pass

Foo.SOME_INSTANCE = Foo()
```

This will work just fine with your dataclass too, but maybe won't be as friendly to static type checkers as you might like, since we've removed the type annotations on the class variables. If you want to, you can leave the type annotations of the `ClassVar`s in the class, but put the initialization of their values afterwards:

```
@dataclass
class Vector2:
    UNIT_UP    : ClassVar['Vector2']
    UNIT_DOWN  : ClassVar['Vector2']
    UNIT_LEFT  : ClassVar['Vector2']
    UNIT_RIGHT : ClassVar['Vector2']
    ZERO       : ClassVar['Vector2']

    x : int = 0
    y : int = 0

    ...

Vector2.UNIT_UP    = Vector2(0,1)
Vector2.UNIT_DOWN  = Vector2(0,-1)
Vector2.UNIT_LEFT  = Vector2(-1,0)
Vector2.UNIT_RIGHT = Vector2(1,0)
Vector2.ZERO       = Vector2(0,0)
```

Note that I've subscripted the `ClassVar` annotation to specify that they're going to be `Vector2` instances, but the type names are quoted to make them forward references, because the type doesn't exist yet under that name when the annotation is evaluated. The quotation marks won't be necessary in some future version of Python (I think either 3.10 or maybe 4.0, depending on how the version numbering goes for future releases), or you can get the behavior now with `from __future__ import annotations`.